# securely populate form that contains password

Tags: forms, security, passwords

I have a HTML form (not a login/registration one) that requires the user to have the password stored there for using the functionality provided by the form. My problem is that when the form is saved it always keeps the details of the form and with little effort you can see what the value of the password is (either through browser by removing the dots or by just inspecting the element).

Any suggestions for best practices on how to make this password not reflect the actual value. I would like the form to keep the password after being saved but the fact that it's so easy to see the value of the password sort of bothers me.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Comment: Don't get you. What do you mean by saved, submitted? Are you checking the password client side? On the face of it this sounds like you've gone down the wrong path.

Comment: I have a configuration form that based on the values entered grants user access to a certain area of a server. And to get authenticated it also requires the user to enter the password.
Later on the user can come back to this form and reconfigure it (if the user wants access to a different part of the server than the one he has now.) When the user comes back to this form the form is already populated with his previous settings (including password which is hidden with the dots masking). IF someone checks the source though the password is visible. 

Hope this makes more sence :)

Comment: You should be using a the same and hopefully correct authentication mechanism as they do for signon. Should be no different to the way it works when they go back to the logon page. If you want them to re-authenticate, then there are lots of examples of how to do that in whatever tech stack you are using.